# How to fetch data from recyclerview without click

Tags: android, adapter

I have images in my recyclerview and used adapter I want to fetch the image_id of first image from adapter without click on item I just displayed them in a list and want to fetch image id of first image

this is my recyclerinterface class

```
public interface RecyclerViewClickInterface {
void onItemClick(int position);
void getItemId(int position);
```

}

this is my activity want to get image_id of first image in list here how do i specify that image_id should be the id of image at position 0

```
 public void onItemClick(int position) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    int pId = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
    bundle.putInt("id", pId );
    SelectFragment select = new SelectFragment();
    select.setArguments(bundle);
    select.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), select.getTag());
}

@Override
public void getItemId(int position) {
  
    image_id = variations.get(position).getImage_id();
}
```

this is my adapter class

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VariationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Variations variation = variationList.get(position);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(variation.getImage())
            .into(holder.binding.imageclr);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            recyclerViewClickInterface.onItemClick(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further? you said that you want to get the first image id without clicking on item? but then you said you want to get it in onItemSelected this is one, the second thing i don't understand, what do you mean by where one column is identical ?

Comment: @moumenShobakey i'm gettin image_id from item click but if user dont select any image then I want to set image_id by default the id of first image and want to fetch that in my activity so using interface class but its not giving me desired result

Comment: Why don't you just set the image_id to the first item in "variation list" and then change it if an item is selected ? and then you won't need to fetch it from the interface callback you will just get it like so.. adapter.getImageId, tell me if i got it wrong

Comment: @moumenShobakey i don't get it that how can i set image_id of first image in variation list should i do this in adapter

Comment: Yes, if you declared your adapter constructor so that it's initialised with the variations list you can declare a property -property: a variable declared at the top of the class-, make it public and set its value to the first item in the variations list

Comment: Then if a user selected an item, this variable's value changes

Comment: @moumenShobakey but i want to use that first image_id inn my activity

Comment: Get it using adapter.image_id when you need it..

Comment: @moumenShobakey its not working by declaring inn adapter

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure you decalred it public

Comment: @moumenShobakey can you please show me any example i got the id of first item in list but unable to use that in my activity I don't know how to send data from adapter to activity or fragment without intent and without item click

Comment: I am using mobile now :/ but it's simple , it's something like public class Adapter{ public int image_id ....//Code} then in activity you say Adapter adapter = new Adapter() then adapter.image_id that's it

Comment: public class VariationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VariationsAdapter.VariationViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Variations> variationList;
    RecyclerViewClickInterface recyclerViewClickInterface;
    public int imageId;

    public VariationsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Variations> variations, RecyclerViewClickInterface recyclerViewClickInterface){
        this.context = context;
        this.variationList = variations;
        this.recyclerViewClickInterface = recyclerViewClickInterface;
    }

Comment: currentProduct.setImgId(adapter.imageId);  when i use it in my avtivity it crashes my app

Comment: value is stored in public variable when i use it in adapter it works fine but when in activity its not accessing the value by using adapter.imageId

Comment: Yes , that's because you didn't initalise it, int image_id = variationList.imageId that's how it should be declared

Answer (score 0):

To get the first item id just use the below code

```
Variations variationFirst = variationList.get(0);

val imageId = variationFirst.getImageId()
```

Comment: i want to get image id of first item and use it in my activity not just image in case if user don't click on item

Comment: Can you please post Variations class here?

Comment: public class Variations {
    String image;
    int image_id;
    
    public Variations(String image, int image_id) {
        this.image = image;
        this.image_id = image_id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    
    public int getImage_id() {
        return image_id;
    }

    public void setImage_id(int image_id) {
        this.image_id = image_id;
    }

 }